# How can I group table by ObjectId?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I rather vaguely familiar with SQL.

I use Sql Server 2012.

I have this table:

```
|Id  | SiteId| IsNormal|     DateReview            | ObjectId |FrequencyId|InspectionId |
|3379|      5|  1      |    2016-09-08 00:00:00.000|    1019  |     1     |     16      |
|3380|      5|  1      |    2016-09-08 00:00:00.000|    1019  |     1     |     20      |
|3381|      5|  0      |    2016-09-08 00:00:00.000|    1020  |     1     |     16      |
|3382|      5|  1      |    2016-09-08 00:00:00.000|    1020  |     1     |     54      |
```

I need to gruop the table by ObjectId, if at least one row has property false in grupped table it have to be False.

Here the desired groupped table:

```
|Id        | SiteId| IsNormal    |     DateReview          | ObjectId |FrequencyId|InspectionId |
|3379,3380 |    5  |    1        |  2016-09-08 00:00:00.000|    1019  |     1     |     16,20   |
|3382,3381 |    5  |    0        |  2016-09-08 00:00:00.000|    1020  |     1     |     54,16   |
```

IsNormal column is BIT type.

Comment: why in the case of `ObjectId = 1020` you expect `Id  = 3382` and also `IsNormal = False` ? those data are from different rows.... wouldn't it be `Id = 3381` ?

Comment: @msanz, I updateded my question It was mistake, could You see it please.

Comment: have you attempted a solution?

Comment: @Tanner I tried to make group by on objectId but it not works, I get error  it asks for aggreagate functions. but I am not familiar with this issue.

Comment: @Michael: Try my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (3379, 5, CAST(1 AS bit), '2016-09-08 00:00:00.000', 1019, 1, 16),
    (3380, 5, CAST(1 AS bit), '2016-09-08 00:00:00.000', 1019, 1, 20),
    (3381, 5, CAST(0 AS bit), '2016-09-08 00:00:00.000', 1020, 1, 16),
    (3382, 5, CAST(1 AS bit), '2016-09-08 00:00:00.000', 1020, 1, 54)
    ) T(Id, SiteId, IsNormal, DateReview, ObjectId, FrequencyId, InspectionId)
)
SELECT Id, SiteId, IsNormal, DateReview, ObjectId, FrequencyId, InspectionId
FROM
(
    SELECT ObjectId, MIN(SiteId) SiteId,
        CONVERT(bit, MIN(CONVERT(int, IsNormal))) IsNormal,
        MIN(DateReview) DateReview, MIN(FrequencyId) FrequencyId
    FROM Src
    GROUP BY ObjectId
) Dist
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+CONVERT(varchar(10),Id)
    FROM Src
    WHERE ObjectId=Dist.ObjectId
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
) Ids(Id)
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+CONVERT(varchar(10),InspectionId)
    FROM Src
    WHERE ObjectId=Dist.ObjectId
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
) InspectionIds(InspectionId)
```

Comment: Example was fixed.

Comment: Hi Pawel.Any idea is it possible to speed up the query above? CROSS APPLY takes amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
 DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    Id INT
    ,SiteId INT
    ,IsNormal bit
    ,DateReview DATETIME
    ,ObjectId INT
    ,FrequencyId INT
    ,InspectionId INT
    )

Insert into @Table values 
 (3379,5,1, '2016-09-08 00:00:00.000',1019,1,16)
,(3380,5,1, '2016-09-08 00:00:00.000',1019,1,20)
,(3381,5,0,'2016-09-08 00:00:00.000',1020,1,16)
,(3382,5,1, '2016-09-08 00:00:00.000',1020,1,54)

SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), Id)
            FROM @Table t
            WHERE t.ObjectId = t1.objectid
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS Id
    ,siteid
    ,CASE 
        WHEN STUFF((
                    SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), IsNormal)
                    FROM @Table t
                    WHERE t.ObjectId = t1.objectid
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '') LIKE '%0%'
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END AS IsNormal
    ,datereview
    ,objectid
    ,FrequencyId
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + convert(VARCHAR(10), InspectionId)
            FROM @Table t
            WHERE t.ObjectId = t1.objectid
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS InspectionId
FROM @Table t1
GROUP BY siteid
    ,datereview
    ,objectid
    ,FrequencyId
```

Comment: Thank you for help.But I made some mistake on my question the IsNormal column if bit column and not string.could you see please my update.